# Can Mathematica poll the dimensions of the individual monitors of its host computer?

Tags: linux, display, system, hardware

The command

```
SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]
```

returns the screen area in the monitors connected to its host computer:

```
{{"ScreenArea" -> {{65, 3200}, {24, 1080}}, 
  "FullScreenArea" -> {{0, 3200}, {0, 1080}}, 
  "BitDepth" -> 24, "Resolution" -> 96}}
```

However, if there are multiple monitors (e.g. in this case one 1920x1080 plus one 1280x1024) then this will only return the total area on my *vanilla Ubuntu  14.04* box. It seems, however, that *Windows 7* and *MacOS 10.10.3* do provide a suitable list of rules for each monitor.

Is it possible to poll, in a platform-independent way, the dimensions of each individual monitor?

Comment: Can I ask what system you're running?

Comment: I am on a Macbook Pro running MacOS 10.10.3 and when I have an additional monitor (in addition to the notebook's display) connected via thunderbolt I get a list containing two entries like the one shown in your post above. Each entry corresponds to one monitor and seems to be correct.

Comment: @Wizard and Kuba, thanks for the input. It seems it's either just a soup, or simply linux hardware support that's the issue, then. Or something.

Comment: This is a known issue on Linux. As a workaround, the system could be queried directly, e.g. `xrandr -q | grep " connected "`.

Comment: @ilian Is `xrandr` something I can assume a general user will have? (beyond the security risk of having an external command)

Comment: In principle, the [RandR](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR/) extension should be integrated in any reasonably modern X server. But surely some configurations exist where this may fail.